# Why do we omit the “are”

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> The techniques **used/are used** by the author in his last book are    quite different from those in his previous works

I came across this question in a textbook and I don’t really understand it.I thought that the relative clause was the subject of the sentence and since it’s the subject it can’t be omitted.So the answer should be sth like ”that are used” or “which are used” But they weren’t in the given options.

Let’s assume that the relative clause is the object of the sentence then what makes **”used”** the true answer? I get that we omit “that” but why we also omit **“are”**? I also have a hard time differentiating between subject and object clauses because the rules are a bit different from the ones in my native language.

Comment: "_The techniques are used by the author in his last book are quite different from those in his previous works_" is ungrammatical, because you have the second 'are' before 'quite different'.  You should make it a separate clause ("in his last book, _and are_ quite different"), or omit the 'are' before 'the techniques'.

Comment: If included, the relativizer ***that*** functions as a subject noun for the verb ***are***. But if that "noun" isn't present there's no reason to include the verb either.

Comment: Thanks so much guys I sincerely appreciate it Just one more question How can I distinguish between subject and object clauses ? This one seemed like a subject clause to me but apparently it was an object.Do you have any tips for differentiating them easily?

Comment: "That" does **not** function as a subject noun. The function of relative "that" is always **marker**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is correct to insert “*that are*” as you suggest, “*that*” is often omitted in such constructions. Once omitted, “*are*” no longer has a subject so disappears too, leaving the correct “*... techniques used by ...”*

There is relevant discussion in the BBC’s “Learning English” website:

“omitting that as relative pronoun

When that is the object in a relative clause, we normally leave it out:

The work (that / which) she does for this company is much appreciated.

The representatives of the company (that / who) I met in Portugal were very helpful.”

[BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv336.shtml)